# Downloading Garmin Express to connect with Vivofit

Tags: drivers

I'd like to set up Garmin Express to sync my vivofit with my computer. There is a lovely (I assume) garmin communicator plugin for ubuntu here:

http://www.andreas-diesner.de/garminplugin/doku.php?id=installation

and a youtube video of someone supposedly setting it up here:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ymuz6owx7n4

but I can't seem to actually bring anything up from there. I'm very new to linux so it may totally just be an issue of me not knowing what I'm doing and just need to know where to look in the menus. I installed the Synaptic manager and the packages indicated (though I'm looking for Vivofit, not Forerunner) and am not sure where to go from there.

Any help is appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, this plugin does not support Vivofit from Garmin. The only solution, I think, is to emulate Windows in VirtualBox.